# TinyTDS: chek if query succeded

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server-2008, ruby-on-rails-4, tiny-tds

I am using tiny_tds gem in a rails project (working with a legacy MSSQL 2008 database)

I execute the following query:

```
update_comment_result = self.get_pmi_client.execute("UPDATE UECOMCLI SET COMMENT = '" + params[:comment] + "' " +
        "WHERE ECKTSOC = '" + params[:lcktsoc] + "' AND ECKTNUMERO = '" + params[:lcktnumero] + "' AND ECKTINDICE = '" + params[:lcktpsf] + "' \n" +
        "IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 \n
        INSERT INTO UECOMCLI (ECKTSOC, ECKTNUMERO, ECKTINDICE, COMMENT) VALUES ('" + params[:lcktsoc] + "', '" + params[:lcktnumero] + "', '" + params[:lcktpsf] + "', '" + params[:comment] + "')")
```

After that, I am unable to find out if the query succeded or not. I have tried using:

```
update_comment_result.affected_rows
```

which returns `-1`

I also tried

```
update_comment_result.each
update_comment_result.return_code
```

which returns `nil`

and

```
update_comment_result.each
update_comment_result.affected_rows
```

which returns `-1`

The query succeeds because the change is made in the database, so why the faulty results?

How can I check if the query succeeded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call 'execute' method, your sql does not actually run. TinyTDS sends it to sql server only when you begin manipulating results, and if there is an error, you can catch it

```
res = Client.Execute('sql script')
begin
    res.entries #now sql script is being sent to the sql server
rescue => e
    puts e
end
```